# How to listen to custom events from outside any custom element in Polymer Dart 1.0?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I can't figure out how to set-up an event listener for the `headerState` property of `PaperScrollHeaderPanel` **outside** of a custom element (specifically from the `main` function).

I have tried various ways, but nothing triggers my callback:

```
headerPanel.on['headerState-changed'].listen((_) => ...);
```

or

```
headerPanel.addEventListener('headerState-changed', (_) => ...);
```

or declaratively

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel on-headerstate-changed="handleHeaderStateChanged" ...>
```

I have tried this with and without the `@reflectable` annotation on the function, as I am not certain if that even has any effect outside of a Polymer custom element.

I do know how to set-up event handlers inside of custom elements or when using a dom-bind template, but I believe there is supposed to be a way to do it without and it's bugging me to wrap my entire `<body>` in a custom element just to receive an event.

I am currently using:

```
polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.10
web_components: ^0.12.1
reflectable: ^0.5.0
polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first code example should wor. What Polymer version are you using? How does your main look like?

Comment: Polymer version is 1.0.0-rc.10. The main starts with an `await initPolymer();` , followed by a few querySelectors and then the event listener registration. I do register a few `tap` events on buttons afterwards using the same method and those work. It appears that the problem is with notifying properties.Come to think of it I actually had the same problem in a custom element trying to receive the `selectedItem` event from a `neon-animated-pages` element, I had to register an `@Listener(pages.iron-select)` and call `notifyPath('pages.selectedItem')` to handle the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
headerPanel.on['headerState-changed'].listen((_) => ...);
```

should probably be

```
headerPanel.on['header-state-changed'].listen((_) => ...);
```

Attribute names are case-sensitive and Polymer converts them from/to camelcase/snakecase

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, but I have already tried it with this name as well (and I just double checked). No luck unfortunately.

Comment: I guess the problem is then that the `polymer_elements` package includes an older version of the JS component  where this property doesn't notify. You might need to investigate the source to find out. I hope there will be an update soon.

Comment: You are right, I should have checked that! It indeed doesn't notify... I guess I'll join the queue waiting for an update. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in a comment, the problem is that the `headerState` property in the Dart version of polymer-elements currently does not *notify*. I have worked around this for now by listening to the `paper-header-transform` event instead:

```
headerPanel.on['paper-header-transform'].listen((_) => ...);
```